# Customize appearance of up/down arrows in HTML number inputs

Tags: jquery, input

I'm interested in sticking with some basic HTML elements to let users increment the value in a number input field.

I know this is possible through Javascript/JQuery rewiring, but is it possible to interact with these arrows without JS?

[image: Up/down arrows]

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can (webkit only I assume):

```
<style>
input[type=number] {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:8px;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}    
input[type=number]:hover::-webkit-inner-spin-button { 
    background: #eee url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYySO.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;  
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
    border-radius: 28px;
}
</style>

<input type="number" value="0">
```

[See JSFiddle method 1](http://jsfiddle.net/BnEmn/150/)

[See JSFiddle method 2](http://jsfiddle.net/BnEmn/1/)

[Reference](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/turn-off-number-input-spinners/)

[image: bg image]

Comment: Because firebase is not -webkit engine based