# Style input type=number

Tags: html, css

I have this input type:

```css
input[type=number] {
    width:9vw;
 height:10vw;
 max-width:42px;
 max-height:52px;
 text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
 border-radius:1px;
 text-align:center;
 border:3px solid black;
 display:inline-block;
 margin-left:6%;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<input type="number"  MIN="0" MAX="15"  default="2" >
```

I noticed that the display changes with different browsers. I I would set the arrows always visible and which cover the entire height. I would only white arrows on a black background. I need also to set default value to 2. thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to set the arrow in the input box as well????

Answer (score 1):

You don't use default.  You use value:

```
<input type="number"  MIN="0" MAX="15"  value="2" >
```

*Your min and max will be ignored.  That should be handled with Javascript.*
That is not true. It actually works fine.  Plus, it even auto-filters bad values.

As far as the looking different part...  You have a condition in your style to allow for different browsers.  That may or may not be overridden at render time.

Comment: Part of this is incorrect; the `min` and `max` values are pretty well adhered to as long as set in an HTML5 document. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp

Answer (score 1):

As durbnpoisn said, you can simply set a `value` attribute to fix your default value problem.

Since you gave your input field a type, you're referencing to the HTML5 input field, which automatically includes those arrows. To get some custom arrows, you have to play around with `-webkit-appearance: none;`. In order to do so, I've found 2 simple explanations to achieve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790935/can-i-hide-the-html5-number-input-s-spin-box) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537234/customize-appearance-of-up-down-arrows-in-html-number-inputs).

Combined together this would look somehow like this:

```
<input type="number" value="2">

input[type=number] {
  width: 9vw;
  height: 10vw;
  max-width: 42px;
  max-height: 52px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
    background: #eee url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYySO.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;  
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    right: 4px;
    border-radius: 28px;
}
```

You can also check this in a little [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1u5crxch/).