# CSS : Want an input type number CSS just like google

Tags: html, css, input

I am trying to make the css of `input type number` just like in the Google Chrome.
but it is not working in my mozila browser.

[image]

I don't know how to make it just like it is seen in Google chrome.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    width:8px;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
  }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:before,
  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:after {
    content: "^";
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    font-family:monospace;
    line-height:1px;
  }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:before {
    top:0px;
  }

  input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button:after {
    bottom:0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" value="10" max="15">
```

Comment: that is an html5 input type that is not supported by all versions of browsers

Comment: That looks like an ASP textbox control using TextMode="Number" rendered in Chrome.

Comment: yes.. but i want to make it same for all browsers and want to give css as seen in google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't use **pseudo** classes on the `::webkit-inner-spin-button`.

#### See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24538648/484780) for a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BnEmn/150/)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button)

[image]

Comment: yes.. but i want to make it same for all browsers and want to give css as seen in google chrome.

Comment: Right, the example linked above does that – but `::webkit` prefixes by definition won't work in every browser

Comment: can't I use for mozilla by putting prefix as `-moz`

Comment: No, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-inner-spin-button)