# How to select with css indicator in <input type="time">?

Tags: css, html, input, css-selectors, frontend

How to select with css indicator ( arrows )  in `<input type="time">` ?

I want to style them.

Comment: `type="time"` works the same as `type="number"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537234/customize-appearance-of-up-down-arrows-in-html-number-inputs

Comment: https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/Iyewu

Comment: I want select only this "Indicator" ( arrow up and arrow down).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input[type="time"]{
    /**style goes here **/
 }
```

If you want to select the spinner (which you say "arrow") you can do that by the css below,

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
        /**style goes here **/
    }
```

But unfortunately this will work for chrome, but not for firefox, since firefox does not work with webkit engine,

Above all, I would like to suggest you, to make custom spinner (which you say "arrow") like this code link. Hope you will find the solution this way. :)

https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb

Comment: I want select only this "Indicator" ( arrow up and arrow down).

Comment: ow, In that case , you can do that by the css below instead of the above one,

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{
        display: none;
    }

but unfortunately this will work for chrome, but not for firefox, since firefox does not work with webkit engine, 

Above all, I will like to suggest you, to make custom spinner (which you say "arrow") like this code link. Hope you will find the solution this way. :)

https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb