# How to hide am/pm from input type time in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I have already tried the code, it's working for chrome but not for firefox

```
input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field {
   display: none;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=time]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 9px; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can customize this input in Firefox, see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247071/how-to-select-with-css-indicator-in-input-type-time

Comment: How to make input text which can take hour and min as input in angularjs

Comment: `input[type="time"]::datetime-edit-field {display: none !important;}` doesn't work in Waterfox Classic or Firefox 83. Looks like folks are stuck using `type="text"` and having to manually fixing everything with JavaScript until someone comes along and applies pressure.