# Display increment/ decrement arrow as disabled when max/min value is reached in number type field

Tags: css, typescript, input, angular-material

I have an input field with type is number . Is it possible to display or style the increment arrow disabled when max value is reached similarly decrement arrow disabled when min value is reached ?

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

When 1 is reached decrement arrow should appear as greyed out and when 5 is reached increment arrow should appear as greyed out.

Comment: clicking the arrows at the limits doesn't change the number already, is this purely for styling?

Comment: @depperm Yes .. just to show the user min or max value is reached . And user cannot increase/ decrease further

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44590932/3462319) but this doesn't mention disabling, just styling

Comment: looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45396280/3462319) you could take one of the answers and then add own styling to the buttons